# Pie chart in jQuery Mobile not showing up

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, pie-chart

I develop a jQuery mobile site and want to display pie chart, the data fetch form database to show in pie chart. Since the jQuery mobile link to another page using div, I make one div in index.php to display data from database, then when the data is showing up, I can view the data by click on the view link. At this part, I make jQuery load to load page piechart.php when click on the view link. The piechart.php page success called by jQuery load, but pie chart not appear, BUT if I right click on page and click view inspect element, it starts showing up normally the pie chart.

Why do I need to right click to display it??

This is index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>SSPIC</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="This site was created from a template originally designed and developed by Codify Design Studio. Find more free templates at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/author_bios/chris_converse.html" />
    <link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/formcalculations.js"></script>

      <link href="styles/cakeform.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/my_company.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/overrides.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/custom.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

          <link href="stylesheets/app.css" media="screen, projector, print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <link href="stylesheets/pizza.css" media="screen, projector, print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

       <script src="javascripts/vendor/snap.svg.js"></script> 
       <script src="javascripts/pizza.js"></script> 

         <script type="text/javascript">
    function MM_popupMsg(msg) { //v1.0
      alert(msg);
    }
         </script>
   </head>
    <body onload='hideTotal()'>

        <div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Homepage</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li class="btn_a"><a href="#about_us">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="btn_s"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li class="btn_l"><a href="#locations">Search</a></li>
                <li class="btn_c"><a href="#contact_us">Upload</a></li>
                <li class="btn_c"><a href="#chart">Chart</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="">
        </div>
    </div>





    <div data-role="page" id="locations" data-title="Find a Locations">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Search Data</h1>
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext">back</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p></p>
            <h2>Search Data</h2>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
            </div>
            <h4>©2013 SSPIC</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="contact_us" data-title="Contact Us">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Upload</h1>
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext">back</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" class="content_container">
            <p><form action="insertimage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
                  <h2 align="center">&nbsp;</h2>
                  <h2 align="center">Information</h2>
                  <table width="63%" border="1" align="center">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="40%">Upload File</td>
                      <td width="60%"><input name="pic" type="file" id="pic" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="2"><div align="center">
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
                      </div></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
                  <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
                  <p align="center">                      
                </form></p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
            </div>
            <h4>©2013 SSPIC</h4>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div data-role="page" id="chart" data-title="chart Us" class="chart">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Pie Chart</h1>
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext">back</a>
        </div>
        <div id="output" data-role="content" class="content_container"></div>
        <div data-role="content" class="content_container" id="k_chart">
            <p>


            <form action="insertimage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
                  <h2 align="center">&nbsp;</h2>
                  <h2 align="center">Display File</h2>
                  <table width="63%" border="1" align="center" class="table_chart">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="40%">Bil</td>
                      <td width="60%">Pusat rawatan</td>
                      <td width="60%">Pengasas</td>
                      <td width="60%">Bil pengamal</td>
                      <td width="60%">Total</td>
                      <td width="60%">Phone number</td>
                      <td width="60%">Peratus</td>
                      <td width="60%">view chart</td>
                    </tr>
                  <?php 
                  include("connection.php");

                  $sel = mysql_query("select * from info");
                  $a = 1;
                  while($get_sel = mysql_fetch_array($sel))
                  {
                  ?>
                  <tr>
                      <td width="40%"><?php echo $a++;?></td>
                      <td width="60%"><?php echo $get_sel['nama_PusatRawatan'];?></td>
                      <td width="40%"><?php echo $get_sel['nama_Pengasas'];?></td>
                      <td width="60%"><?php echo $get_sel['bilangan_Pengamal'];?></td>
                      <td width="40%"><?php echo $get_sel['totalPrice'];?></td>
                      <td width="60%"><?php echo $get_sel['phonenumber'];?></td>
                      <td width="60%"><?php echo $get_sel['peratus'];?></td>
                      <td width="60%"><div class="id"><?php echo $get_sel['id'];?></div><span class="viewBtn">View</span></td>
                    </tr>
                   <?php 
                  }
                  ?>
                  </table>
                  <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
                  <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
                  <p align="center">                      
                </form></p>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
            </div>
            <h4>©2013 SSPIC</h4>
        </div>
    </div>


     <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            // Pizza.init();
            $('.viewBtn').on('click',function()
            {
                 var id = $(this).closest('td').find('.id').text();

                $('#k_chart').hide();
                $('#output').load("piechart.php?id="+id);//load page to display pie chart

            });


            $(window).load(function() {

                Pizza.init({
                donut: false, // enable donut chart
                donut_inner_ratio: 0.4,   // between 0 and 1
                percent_offset: 35, // relative to radius
                stroke_color: '#333',
                stroke_width: 0,
                show_percent: true, // show or hide the percentage on the chart.
                animation_speed: 500,
                animation_type: 'elastic' // options: backin, backout, bounce, easein, easeinout, easeout, linear
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
      </html>
```

This one is piechart.php

```
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/my_company.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/overrides.css" />
<link href="stylesheets/app.css" media="screen, projector, print" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
<link href="stylesheets/pizza.css" media="screen, projector, print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script><script src="javascripts/vendor/snap.svg.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/pizza.js"></script> 

  <div data-role="content" class="content_container">
<p>
  <div id="jquery-script-menu">
<div class="jquery-script-center">
<div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<h1 style="margin-top:150px;" align="center">Papar peratus lulus pie chart </h1>
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
<h3>Graphs</h3>
</div>
</div>
<?php 
include("connection.php");
$id_info = $_GET['id'];
$papar = mysql_query("select *from info where id = '$id_info'");
$get_papar = mysql_fetch_array($papar);
if($get_papar['peratus']>0 and $get_papar['peratus']<=50)
{
$xlulus = $get_papar['peratus'];
$lulus = 100 - $xlulus;
}
else
 {
$lulus = $get_papar['peratus'];
$xlulus = 100 - $lulus;
 }
?>
<div class="row">
<div class="large-4 small-4 columns">
<ul data-pie-id="svg">
<li data-value="<?php echo $xlulus;?>">Tidak memenuhi syarat</li><li data-value="<?php  echo $lulus;?>">Memenuhi syarat</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="large-8 small-8 columns">
<div id="svg"></div>
</div>
</div>
</p>
</div>
```

The jQuery code is at the bottom of page index.php..

Answer (score 2):

You need to correctly time your plugin initialization.

First forget about document ready and window load, they will not work correctly with jQuery Mobile application (usually they trigger before jQuery Mobile content is successfully enhanced).

Instead you should learn how to use jQuery Mobile page events, for example pageinit event exists to replace document ready.

Read more about it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**.

Now regarding your main problem, your plugin must be initialized during the pageshow event. A lot of visual plugins (carousels, charts ..) require correct page height. When working with jQuery Mobile page height is correctly calculated only during pageshow event, it will be 0 in any other case.

Page event initialization order can be found **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/page-events-order-in-jquery-mobile/)**.

Comment: can't find solution,dont know how to use it @Gajotres.. can u give me some example related with my problem,,

Comment: Show me whose pizza chart implementation you used and I will create you a working example.

Comment: this is link for pie chart that i used. http://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/Responsive-Pie-Chart-Plugin-wit-jQuery-Snap-SVG-Pizza.html .. if not bother u, i can send to u my project..

Comment: Mail it to draga.gaic@gmail.com you should also include dump of table info

Comment: this is ur address right.. draga.gaic@gmail.com .. i got mailer-demon

Comment: sry dragan.gaic@gmail.com